# Problem accessing remix via mac

Tags: remix

I'm trying to learn Solidity and trying to access remix web [page](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.14+commit.c2215d46.js) (using MacBook pro), the page loads but it halts after that and I cannot scroll up and down the page to see the code.

Do I need to install anything to use online remix compiler?

If the question is irrelevant, please let me know before downvoting, so I'll remove it.

Edit: I'm using Safari web browser (with default setting).

Comment: Are you using the Javascript.vm?  The other options won't work if you don't have it set up

Comment: @thefett Yes, I am.  I won't even reach to the point where I can select one of the options. The browser stops after it loads and I can't do anything. Later on, I'll try what's suggested in the answer and provide an update.

Comment: It's good and useful that you posted that you're using a MacBook Pro (and presumably macOS); it would be even more helpful when describing problems with web pages if you also include your browser. Not sure if it's relevant in this particular case, but it might be.

Comment: @lungj Thanks for the comment. I've specified the web browser I'm using in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be the computer you are using, but rather the web browser that you are using and/or the plugins/extensions that you have installed.

You do not need to install anything to use Remix - that is what is so great about it. Try disabling any adblockers etc that may be stopping the Javascript files loading correctly.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I changed the web browser to google chrome and works fine now. Initially, I was using Safari and I disabled adblockers but it didn't work.